# Access Average Problems Between Names and Dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, report, average

I have a database that is more or less the following:

John Smith
    Jan 1 2016
    Sales $80
Jan 2 2016
Sales $100

Jane Doe
Jan 1 2016
Sales $85
Jan 2 2016
Sales $110

My report is setup to break on names and on dates (b/c in actuality there are more numbers than just sales, but I'm simplifying this question).
I need to find the average for a week, rolling 4 weeks, and month for each person.  I can control the date range specified in the report using a form I made so I can get them to click a button that autofills a range of time based on today (a week would be the previous 7 days, etc).

I cannot however figure out how to make it average everything under a name.  Using Avg, DAvg, and some "grouping" controls have not resulted in anything useable.  DAvg got me the closest but it would average EVERYONE together instead of breaking each person by their name (which is "Employee Name" in the query).

Any help or ideas would be vastly appreciated!  I don't care if it is a modification to the query language or the report itself as I'm versed in VBA, SQL, and Access to an extent.  I came from doing things in Excel, so I'm no Access pro, but I'm great with Excel.  Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem here haha!  Oh wait, that's not funny...doh!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It should follow this line:

```
Select Person, Avg(Sales), Format(yyyymm, [Date])
From YourTable
Group By Person, Format(yyyymm, [Date])
```

For weeks it gets a little more complicated as weeks cross New Year.

Comment: Is there not a "calculated field" formula I can use of any kind?  Doing what you have above, I don't see how where the days of the month are figured in?  Our calendar is a fiscal calendar, so they user actually chooses Jan 01, 2016 in one field and Jan 07, 2016 in another field if they want a week.  It looks like though if I just take the date out of the grouping it makes it work to an extent, but I'd like it as a calculated field if at all possible (using something like DAvg where I can specify some kind of condition).

Comment: The query as is calculates for the entire table. If you only want for an interval, just insert a _Where_ clause and parameters for a _FromDate_ and _ToDate_.

Comment: Okay.  I will give that a try either today or Monday. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: I tried your solution applied to my info, no luck.  It doesn't average the "Sales" across dates, it's like it just gives me the average sales on that single day which is just the raw data number.

Comment: Of course, if you filter on a single date, there is nothing to average. You must filter on an interval - like a month as I showed.